# ModX if statement in a parameter

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am new to ModX revolution, and can't figure it out. I need to show pages with parent from url (e.g. clinic=21) and if no clinic set then set parents to a list. I've got this:

```
[[!getPage? 
    &elementClass=`modSnippet` 
    &element=`getResources` 
    &parents=[[!If? `[[!searchFieldClinic? &field=`clinic`]]`=`` &then=`127,106` &else=`[[!searchFieldClinic? &field=`clinic`]]`]]
    ]]
```

but the if always returns `127,106,70,76,83,93,92,99,113,120,134,148,155,162,169,176,704,975,183`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself, thanks :)

```
[[!getPage? 
    &elementClass=`modSnippet` 
    &element=`getResources` 
    &parents=[[!If?
       &subject=`[[!searchFieldClinic? &field=`clinic`]]`
       &operator=`EQ`
       &operand=``
       &then=`127,106,70,76,83,93,92,99,113,120,134,148,155,162,169,176,704,975,183`
       &else=`[[!searchFieldClinic? &field=`clinic`]]`
    ]]
]]
```